# Place image on text with effects - Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, fill, clipping-mask

I have a logo where I have applied effects to the text. I have a transparent image of some stars I would like to apply over the text but when I create a clipping mask it removes the colour of the text. I tried to create a pattern of the image and apply the pattern but that also removes the text colour. How can I keep the text colour / effects and place the stars image over it.

Im still new to Illustrator but have experience in photoshop where I can easily do this with a clipping mask.

Thanks for any help in advance. Maybe im just doing something simply wrong?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What is an "image of some starts"?  Any chance you could share an image showing what you are trying to achieve, and what has failed.  A picture is worth a thousand words!

Comment: Meant to write Stars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clipping masks in Illustrator aren't the same as in Photoshop. In fact, they are sort of reversed.

---

In Photoshop...

- Layer containing content to be clipped
- Layer defining boundaries of clip area (text layer, shape layer, etc)

Then you <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>-click between the layers and the top layer is clipped to the bottom layer.

---

In Illustrator....

- Shape defining clipping mask
- Content to be clipped

Then you select both objects and choose `Edit > Clipping mask > Make` and the bottom object is clipped to the shape of the top object.

The difference is in Illustrator you need the shape defining the clipping mask **above** whatever is going to be clipped.

---

If you want to retain the base object appearance and add an *additional* clipping mask on top of it, you may need 3 objects (or compound shapes)

- Clipping mask shape
- Content to be clipped
- Base shape for appearance

You then use the top 2 to create a clipping mask. Then possibly *group* that clipping mask with the bottom object to retain the base appearance.

---

This is merely a cursory explanation. Without some images it's difficult to provide exact execution for any specific artwork.

---

From what I could gather, you perhaps have the clipping shape *below* content and are getting the wrong clipping.